# Different ways to run Player Creation in Paranoia

Tags: paranoia-2017

I am now looking at running my 5th Paranoia session and this will be the 4th time the players have used the Player generation system from the New Paranoia system (pick a stat player to your left/right etc gets a -ve value)

Now seeing as how the players are used to this system of player generation I wondered if anyone had any suggestions for alternatives?

Are there any other alternatives GM's have used to make this process less predictable for the players? Have any alternatives been given in other books or online by the designers?

Comment: this seems like a matter of opinion. Can you reword your question, perhaps to ask if there are published, alternate character creation rules?

Comment: Right, “give me ways to mix it up a bit” is an idea-generation or collection question we don't handle. If you have a specific problem, you can request our advice in resolving it -- but “the players are used to how character generation works” does not sound like a problem. If it's predictable, in what way is it predictable and how does that manifest as a problem? (Are they always picking the same stat or something?)

Comment: question edited to make it less opinion based. please consider for reopening

Comment: “Any suggestions” is automatically too broad a question for a Stack to handle. If you're looking for ideas, a Stack is the wrong tool for the job just due to how the site's voting system functions, and the rules for questions that ensure the voting system works as intended. If you want to solicit ideas from people, the fitting tool for that job is a discussion forum. This mismatch comes up often enough that we've put together [a list of RPG discussion forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449) to browse and pick from, as a way to help people who have questions we can't otherwise help.